# What does it mean when someone says "...it scales with..."?

Tags: scaling

I frequently hear people say something scales with the mass m, or the length l, etc.

What does that mean?

Let's take a concrete example, the force equation F = ma.

Does this mean that F scales with m?

Or, if we have something like moment of inertia = $I = l^2$ * ...

where l denotes the length of a solid, then do we say that " the moment of inertia scales with $l^2$"?

Comment: A number of comments that weren't going anywhere useful deleted. The best response to a comment you don't care for on a personal level is to either flag it or not but then *move on*. No one is going to win the internet in the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unmodified the phrase probably means "is proportional to", but it can be modified to mean other functional relationships. For instance *"scales quadratically with"* or *"scales as the square of"* indicate a relationship like
$$ x \propto y^2\;.$$

In sloppy usage it might mean "depends on" with the functional dependence left unstated (but presumably known to the listener).

Other adjectives that appear with non-trivial frequency include "inversely" "exponentially", "by the inverse square", and "logarithmically". Cubic, quartic, hyperbolic, and other relationships are less common.

Answer (score 0):

In the sense of the Original Post's question, $F=ma$ means (in case you're trying the figure the net force magnitude from the the particle movement)  that $F$ scales linearly with both the mass and the acceleration. And the meaning of that statement is that, if the mass were twice larger, than the $F$ should also be (to cause the same acceleration $a$), and if $a$ is ten times larger, than so should $F$.

Similarly, the area of a circle scales with its radius $r^2$, so for a radius 3 times as large, the corresponding area will be $3^2=9$ times larger.